# Need help packaging a webservice client jar in Java

Tags: java, web-services, maven, maven-shade-plugin, java-client

We have a series of web service APIs that we have also written clients for so that we can easily re-use them in other Java applications. I now have need to be able to use the clients in an environment outside of a webserver. I used the maven-assembly-plugin to create a zip containing all of the client's dependencies and it worked fine except for the dependencies that would be provided by wildfly. I added the appropriate resteasy jar files to a command line app and everything works. Now I would like to be able to package the client 2 ways; with the resteasy jars and without. The apache shade plugin looks like a good option to do this but I can't see how to include an extra dependency (resteasy) that is not referenced in the project. Has anyone done this?

Edit:
I have tried both the maven-assembly-plugin and maven-shade. Shade looked promising until I attempted to deploy the jar. I got security warnings assumedly because the dependency jars that it repackaged were signed and so repackaging them caused errors. In any case it looks like using profiles is part of the key. I can set up a separate profile in the pom that will include the resteasy dependencies and so include them only when desired.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking at this question, I haven't completely solved this but adding a profile is part of the key. If you add a profile to your pom, you can add the resteasy dependencies only under that profile. If you add the maven-assembly-plugin and the resteasy dependencies under that profile, you can build a jar containing all of the dependencies without affecting you regular release.